# Call buttonClick from different function C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, function, button

I have the following button which performs some function

```
        public void btnTurn90_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Turn(-118);
    }
```

and I want to call it in another function

```
            public void move()
         {
            btnTurn90_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());

         }
```

the thing is I want EventArgs to have a new value every time I call the button inside the function and that's not working with me

Thanks

Comment: "and that's not working with me" is extremely vague. Please provide a [mcve] with far more detail. (Also, creating a new object for the sender argument is probably a bad idea - it would be more idiomatic to use `this`.)

Comment: btnTurn90_Click is not a method is an event handler, what yo are trying to do is not valid

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you're looking for is called : `PerformClick()`

```
public void move()
{
    btnTurn90.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I try that but PerformClick() cannot be reached, I use Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Ahh, okay. Then you'll have to follow [David's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47794432/7875013).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling button event from function, just export code from event and create function call it from both of it

Comment: Because on click button there is a new value given to EventArgs e but that will not work if i put it in the function

Comment: pass argument in as function parameter

Comment: I tried that but the argument has been passed keep the first value of the first call and not changing after i call it again

Comment: which argument you are accessing from EventArgs?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to "trick" the UI into thinking something was clicked.  Refactor your code into invokable operations and, well, invoke those.  Any time you have multiple things trying to perform the same operation, that's precisely the use case for moving that code *out* of the UI-coupled event handlers and into something commonly accessible.

Put the code into its own method:

```
private void SomeMeaningfulName()
{
    Turn(-118);
}
```

And invoke that method from your event handler:

```
public void btnTurn90_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeMeaningfulName();
}
```

And from your other code:

```
public void move()
{
    SomeMeaningfulName();
}
```

As the complexity grows, you continue to refactor into distinct classes representing meaningful objects, and so on.  So rather than trying to hard-wire a bunch of UI-coupled event handlers together, you end up with meaningfully named objects and operations which work together simply and easily.  The code which invokes those operations starts to look less like a hacked together UI and more like a prose description of the logic being performed.

Comment: actually, i am editing in some existing sample code that's why I try to access the button like that. however, i try the solution you provide but still not working

Comment: @Omar.J: What did you try and in what way is it "not working"?

Comment: the function Turn(-116) uses click event in an unknown way and when I call the function by pressing the button itself multiple times it works well but when I call the function multiple times from my code without pressing the button the function works for the first time but doesn't work in any next calling, I think the function need random values every time but here with the case of one pressed it would be with a constant value which is the value of the pressing, the same happened with the code you provide it

Comment: @Omar.J: If there's some problem *inside* the `Turn()` method then certainly nobody here can tell you what that problem is without *seeing* that method.  The question you've asked is how to invoke an operation that exists inside of an event handler.  This is a way to do that.  If the operation *itself* is failing, that's outside the scope of what's being shown/asked in the question.  Focus on the specific problem being solved and present information about that problem.  "It doesn't work because of some other reason elsewhere in my code" doesn't help us to help you.